# Criar condição em instrução

Tags: sql, oracle

Olá, eu possuo o seguinte select:

```
SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM user_cons_columns WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'CANCELAMENTO' and table_name = 'NAVIO';
```

Após pegar o nome o mesmo vai pra outra query porém se retornar null eu acabo tendo um erro e interrompe meu script. Como que seria uma condição para vericar se tem resultado ou não? Caso retorne algo, será executado:

```
alter table NAVIO DROP CONSTRAINT || constr_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver utilizando PL-SQL no seu script, pode resolver desta maneira:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR C_CONSTRAINT IS
    SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME 
      FROM user_cons_columns 
     WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'CANCELAMENTO' 
       AND table_name = 'NAVIO';       
  V_CONSTRAINT C_CONSTRAINT%ROWTYPE;       
BEGIN    
    OPEN C_CONSTRAINT;
    LOOP
      FETCH C_CONSTRAINT INTO V_CONSTRAINT;
      EXIT WHEN C_CONSTRAINT%NOTFOUND;
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE NAVIO DROP CONSTRAINT ' || V_CONSTRAINT.CONSTRAINT_NAME;
    END LOOP;
END;
```